# Where is the Trash directory?

Tags: linux-mint, xdgutils

The [trash spec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html) tells me that the Trash directory is here: $XDG_DATA_HOME/Trash

Looking at my environment variables on my Linux Mint system, I find a bunch of XDG stuff, but no XDG_DATA_HOME

I've done some looking, but so far I have not been able to locate the Trash directory. Where is it?

Comment: [Reading a reference always helps](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables).

Comment: Usually it's under `~/.Trash` or `~/.local/share/Trash`, this is literally one of those questions that is a quick Google search away

Comment: If you're using a file manager gui, perhaps you need to enable `Show Hidden Files and Hidden Directories` to see .Trash, et al.

Comment: Found ~/.local/share/Trash on my system. How did you know that? And how are you supposed to find it from inside a program? None of the environment variables contain .local. Lots of 'local' and 'share' but no '.local', and certainly no 'Trash'.

Answer (score 3):

your home trash directory MUST be available and defined.

Usually it's under `~/.Trash` or `~/.local/share/Trash` as default

you can `echo $XDG_DATA_HOME` to display it, if you get nothing, you can set it by yourself.

```
XDG_DATA_HOME=/usr/local/share/
export XDG_DATA_HOME
```

and

```
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share/
export XDG_DATA_DIRS
```

for details see [setting XDG_DATA_DIRS and XDG_DATA_HOME](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157722/setting-xdg-data-dirs-and-xdg-data-home)

and I recommend that you make `trash-cli` as an alternative for the `rm`, it's the command line interface to FreeDesktop.org Trash,

see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trash-cli/0.12.9.14
      https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli

Answer (score 1):

> your home trash directory MUST be available and defined.
> Usually it's under ~/.Trash or ~/.local/share/Trash as default
> you can echo $XDG_DATA_HOME to display it, if you get nothing, you can set >it by yourself.

First it is impossible to set something you cannot find in the first place.
Secondly **env | grep XDG** does not return any variable XDG_DATA_HOME, so that provided no help whatsoever.   Thirdly, Google search on e.g. "where is linux Trash folder stored" does indeed turn up results -- namely this page and others like it.  Search engines are source referrers, not source providers. If someone hasn't already posted it somewhere, it won't show in Google or anywhere else. Suggesting a Google search as an answer is not helpful.

So indeed, **find / -iname trash** will find it (recommend adding **2>/dev/null** to eliminate all errors that will occur for inaccessible files), but novices have a lot of trouble with find's syntax.

So yes, it is usually ~/.Trash or ~/.local/share/Trash.
As for trash-cli, yes very helpful, but the correct instructions for it are:

```
sudo apt install trash-cli -y
alias rm=trash-put
alias rm >> ~/.bashrc  ( or >> ~/.bash_aliases)
```

Now, I would like to know, if I set XDG_DATA_HOME to /tmp, will trashing a file move to /tmp instead?  The concept of a Trash folder is great, but I'd like a little more sophistication like an Archive folder where I can *archive-put* little used files that I still want to keep but keep out of my main folder stash to eliminate clutter. I'm no linux novice, but I do have limited time--so that is why we collaborate--I save you time, you save me time!!  I hope.  Less is more, more or less.